# Old questions that should be migrated here

Tags: discussion

I've been flagging a few of my old posts on math.SE that I feel are more suitable for some of the newer sites that are popping up, including this one. A moderator informed me that questions older than 60 days can't be migrated automatically, and that I should bring the topic up here in meta.

The question I flagged was this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721758/how-can-i-formulate-the-two-guards-puzzle-to-disallow-references-to-the-other-gu

Are there any other questions that are there (that are tagged [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle), obviously) that we think should be moved here instead?

Comment: What the mod meant is that even mods can't migrate questions > 60 days old, so the reason for migration has to be compelling enough for the dev team to step in.

Comment: I see. What would count as a compelling reason, do you think?

Comment: It generally has to be off-topic where it is, but well written and with a reasonably good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Questions are only migrated if they are off-topic. Not if there happens to be another site where they're on-topic.

If someone asks a question on another site, **and it is off-topic there**, the question can be migrated here. But a question about a math puzzle would usually be on-topic on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), so it would not be migrated away from there.

Conversely, if someone asks about a math puzzle here, we wouldn't migrate the question to Math.SE.